# How to avoid duplicate objects?

Tags: javascript, object

I'm making a quiz. A user first chooses how many questions he/she wants to answer and then gets to answer them. After they've answered the questions there is a "Back to start"-button that takes them back to where the page loads. This is all done by hiding and displaying divs using javascript.

Questions are stored as objects within an object. If a user wants to answer 5 questions, 5 random questions will be put in a new object. This object is used to display the question and see how many correct answers the user gets.

When a user has finished a quiz, goes back to the start and starts a new quiz my problem comes. The var that contains the object with the chosen amount of questions doesnt get replaced with the new object containing the new questions. Instead, a completely new var is created with the same name, giving me a TypeError error message in the console.

I've recreated my problem in a simplified manner in this JSFiddle. The first set of buttons can be seen as when the user chooses an amount of questions and the second button when they answer.

https://jsfiddle.net/v2488zxx/

```
    var firstDivClick = document.getElementsByClassName("button-1"),
      secondDivClick = document.getElementsByClassName("button-2");


   for(var i = 0; i < firstDivClick.length; i++) {
    firstDivClick[i].addEventListener("click", function() {      
      var valueAsInt = parseInt(this.textContent),
          object,
          firstDiv = document.getElementById("first-buttons-wrap"),
          secondDiv = document.getElementById("second-buttons-wrap");
      if(valueAsInt === 2) {
        object = {
          one: {
            text: "Where is my bed?"
          },
          two: {
            text: "Where does Santa Claus live?"
          }
        }
      }

      else if(valueAsInt === 3) {
        object = {
          one: {
            text: "Where is my bed?"
          },
          two: {
            text: "Where does Santa Claus live?"
          },
          three: {
            text: "Where does poo live?",
          }
        }
      }                   

      firstDiv.style.display = "none";
      secondDiv.style.display = "block";

      for(var i = 0; i < secondDivClick.length; i++) {
        secondDivClick[i].addEventListener("click", function() { 

          if(this.textContent === "abc") {
            firstDiv.style.display = "block";
            secondDiv.style.display = "none";
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is - your fiddle seems to work fine for me and there's no error on the console.

Answer (score 0):

As vfar as I understood the problem: you need to put the definition of "object" outside the loop:

```
  var firstDivClick = document.getElementsByClassName("button-1"),
      secondDivClick = document.getElementsByClassName("button-2");

  var object; // define globally and empty.

  // For loop so all buttons make an action
  for(var i = 0; i < firstDivClick.length; i++) {

    // Event handler for the buttons with class button-1
    firstDivClick[i].addEventListener("click", function() {

    console.log("----------------------");

      var valueAsInt = parseInt(this.textContent),
          firstDiv = document.getElementById("first-buttons-wrap"),
          secondDiv = document.getElementById("second-buttons-wrap");
          ....
```